# yii1 gridview dropdownlist set value as default value

Tags: php, yii

Is that possible to make **gridview dropdownlist** set value as **default value**? For example my working status has **2 type** which is active and no active. Possible set active as default value? [image]

the code as below:

```
            array(
           'name'=>'employee_wstatus',
            'type'      => 'raw',  

            'filter'=>array('1'=>'Active', '0'=>'No Active'),
            'value' => 'EmployeeM::model()->getWorkstatus($data->employee_wstatus);',     
            'htmlOptions'=> array('width'=>'10%'),

              ),
```

Comment: In Controller : `$searchModel->employee_wstatus = 1;`

Comment: yes! is works! But is that posssible to make the dropdownlist selection value are only have active and no active? because still got a blank value can select.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [implementation of Yii filter method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn#getFilterCellContent-detail), you will see, that it always adds empty option when it gets an array on input.

To remove blank value from your dropdown filter you have to define selectbox manually:

```
'filter' => CHtml::activeDropDownList(
    EmployeeM::model(),
    'employee_wstatus',
    array('1' => 'Active', '0' => 'No Active')
),
```